# How to resolve "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net Core application. I get error messages only during POST communication for one Controller. In the debug environment, the POST communication works fine, but in the production environment, the error message is displayed.POST communication with other controllers is working properly.

```
The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.
Your support ID is: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

There is no error log.
There are no errors in the console and the status is 200.
I replaced the post URL with https://www.google.co.jp/
The above error occurred even after replacing the URL

Comment: There isn’t much to discuss further as the error message isn’t typical from IIS. What kind of environment is it? You indeed need to talk to the server/network administrators first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you have used but this code working for me.

```
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
       public  class Program
       {
          public static async Task Main(string[] args)
         {
            await MakeGetRequestAsync();
         }

    public static async Task MakeGetRequestAsync()
    {
        // Create an instance of HttpClient
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

       

        try
        {
            // Send GET request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com");

            // Check if request was successful
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Read response content as string
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Print the response body
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
            else
            {
                // Print error status code
                Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with status code {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            // Print any caught exceptions
            Console.WriteLine($"Request exception: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your response.
GET communication is working fine with the Controller.
I am having trouble with an error only during POST communication.

Comment: Can you please add your source code so that we have better understanding